# 2 Elements Updating Independently, Rather than as a Whole, Javascript Code Execution Order Issue

Tags: javascript

Been working on this project for a few weeks now:

https://maxview.co.uk/data-usage-calculator-button-input/

Password: Maxview

And since adding in the "tripdays" element, allowing users to input, or increase in steps of 1, their number of days for the trip, I have been experiencing a lag in how the HTML elements to update.

Opening the page above, you will notice if you add in a number of days, it does not update the elements right away, you need to add the days, then click two buttons to make it update.

I am assuming this is something to do with where the event listeners are placed in the code, and perhaps that they are acting separately rather than as a whole, so there is a lag with its updating.

**Desired behavior**

Whenever a button is clicked once, or the number of days is input, both elements update immediately.

I have tried moving the event listeners for the "tripdays" element (the number of days) to various parts of the code to try to get it to act at the same time as the button event listeners but I haven't been successful.

Javascript code below, all elements are in the DOM:

```js
<script>
    

    let totals = {
        "sd_streaming_hours": 0,
        "hd_streaming_hours": 0,
        "video_streaming_hours": 0,
        "music_streaming_hours": 0,
        "nav_hours": 0,
        "gaming_hours": 0,
        "browsing_hours": 0,
        "emails_sent": 0
    };
    
    //This line of code adds an event listener for the "click" event to the "body" element of the HTML document. 
    //The function passed as the second argument to the addEventListener method will be called whenever a click event occurs on the body element. 
    //The e argument passed to the function is the event object that contains information about the event, such as the position of the mouse cursor when the click occurred.
    
    document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    
        //
        
        const el = e.target;
        if (el.classList.contains("btn")) {
            const name = el.name;

            const selected = document.querySelector(".selected[name=" + name + "]");
            if (selected) {
                selected.classList.remove("selected")
            }
            el.classList.add("selected")
            let val = parseInt(el.value);
            switch (name) {
                case "sd_streaming_hours":
                    val = val * 0.1;
                    break;
                case "hd_streaming_hours":
                    val = val * 0.3;
                    break;
                case "video_streaming_hours":
                    val = val * 0.4;
                    break;
                case "music_streaming_hours":
                    val = val * 0.4;
                    break;
                case "nav_hours":
                    val = val * 0.4;
                    break;
                case "gaming_hours":
                    val = val * 0.4;
                    break;
                case "browsing_hours":
                    val = val * 0.4;
                    break;
                case "emails_sent":
                    val = val * 0.4;
                    break;
            }
        
            totals[name] = val
            updateDataUsage();

        }
    });

    //proposed new code to update total data usage and total trip data usage at the same time whenever a button is clicked or a number is an input

    function updateDataUsage(){
        let input = document.getElementById("tripdays");
        let totalDataUsage = document.getElementById("total_data_usage");
        let totalTripDataUsage = document.getElementById("total_trip_data_usage");
        if (input && totalDataUsage && totalTripDataUsage) {
            input = parseFloat(input.value);
            let tripDataUsage = parseFloat(totalDataUsage.textContent);
            let tripDaysInputValue = (input * tripDataUsage)
            totalTripDataUsage.textContent = tripDaysInputValue.toFixed(1) + "GB";
            totalDataUsage.textContent = (totals["sd_streaming_hours"] + totals["hd_streaming_hours"] + totals["video_streaming_hours"] + totals["music_streaming_hours"] + totals["nav_hours"] + totals["gaming_hours"] + totals["browsing_hours"] + totals["emails_sent"]).toFixed(1) + "GB";
        }};
  
        //to default select the first "never" button

   document.getElementById("sdnever").click();

   //default trip days value:

   let tripDays = document.getElementById("tripdays")
    if(tripDays){
        tripDays.value = "1";
        tripDays.addEventListener("change", updateDataUsage);
        tripDays.addEventListener("click", updateDataUsage);

    document.getElementById("tripdays").focus();
    document.getElementById("tripdays").dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    }

</script>
```

Any help or layman's terms advice much appreciated as fairly new to JS but always struggled a bit with code execution orders.

Ben